# Which is better programming practice - Unnecessary parameters or a static variable?

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, static, xna

I am making a game in C# and XNA 4.0 and one of my classes requires its own texture. The class is currently being used like this:

Class constructor:

```
class Item : ItemBase //It uses a base class
{
    public Item(Texture2D myTexture) : base(myTexure)
    {
    }
}
```

New instance:

```
Texture2D m_Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Texture1");
Item m_item = new Item(m_Texture);
```

However, every single new instance of the class will require the same texture (i.e. Every parameter value will be exactly the same). As a result, this parameter feels unnecessary. I was considering changing the constructor to be more like this:

```
public Item() : base(MainClass.m_Texture) //This now takes a public static variable from the main game class
{
}
```

This removes the need for the parameter (less coding on my part), but I was wondering if this would lead to other issues like performance and memory usage.

Overall, which is considered to be better programming practice? Having several class instances that all use the same parameter value or exchanging the constructor parameter for a static variable?

Comment: If it's always going to be the same, why do you need the field at all? Note that your second piece of code is simply invalid - you're still declaring something in the parameter list. It would be easier to help you choose between alternatives if you presented valid code.

Comment: Oops. I left out some important info. The class is actually inheriting from a base. I've edited the code to explain that now. Hopefully that makes the question a bit less confusing.

Comment: Is the texture used anywhere else? If so, why does it need to be a static field in `MainClass`? Why not make it a static field in `Item`?

Comment: Because I'm doing all of the content loading in the MainClass. That's where all of the texture variables are held.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a "God class" to me :( To be honest, at this point we'd be trying to unravel all of your design, working out where you need to create new instances of `Item` etc... I don't think this is going to end up being terribly suitable for SO.

Comment: Coupling you classes to a static instance is a bad design.. that's your answer

Comment: If it is really always the same, I agree with Jon Skeet. You should make it static in the class where it's used.

Comment: @Spivonious So I would change it to something like `Texture2D m_Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Texture1"); Item.Texture = m_Texture;`?

Comment: I'd really have to see the whole design. I agree with you that it's odd to pass in the same parameter every time Item is created. Your initial thought also feels wrong, but I'm not sure of the best way to change it. Something like Michael P's answer feels the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **performance** it's better to have **one static variable** and share it between your classes. But usually the performance impact is close to none, unless it's critical code. (By critical code, I mean code that runs a lot of times in one second, e.g. the *Update* method, or code that causes a bottleneck in your application)

**Otherwise**, I suggest using something that feels **natural** to your code. If all the instances share the same texture at all times, then it's natural to use one variable for that, not copy it several times.

Comment: your 'suggestion' belongs in a comment field.. his code clearly violates Single Responsibility Principal and Seperation of Concern

Comment: I mentioned my suggestion because even thought the answer to his question regarding performance was correct, it could be misleading.

An expert programmer can see some code and mention flaws all day long. This place is for answering questions.

Comment: the usage and considerations of static global variables have little to do with performance. It's more a discussion of accessibility. On that note, do you see a **ref** on his base constructor?  using a static variable in a method, is quite different then passing it to a method..

Answer (score 1):

You can make the texture a singlton.

```
class TextureHolder
{
    static private TextureHolder instance;
    private Texture2D texture;
    private TextureHolder()
    {
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Texture1");

    }

    public static GetTexture()
    {
         if(instance==null)
         {
              instance = new TextureHolder();

         }
         return instance;

    }
```

}

in your class then do this:

```
public Item() : base(TextureHolder.GetTexture()) //This now takes a public static variable from the main game class {}
```

This way if no Items are created, the texture will never be loaded. But if more than 2 items are created, you will load the texture only once and reference it once